# CLI: batch file rename -- with CONTENT ?? (e.g. specific text mentioned in file)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, batch, grep, rename

I would like to batch rename files (*.txt) by inserting a number of the format 'RXR1234567' (RXR+7digits) [if such number (and ideally only one) is found in the text] at the front of the filename, e.g. instead of

```
letter_235.txt
```

the file should be called

```
RXR1234567_letter_235.txt
```

Could this be done from the command line (grep, rename)?
The files are in various subdirectories.

Your thoughts will be appreciated (as always).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the root directory:

```
find -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'PREFIX=`grep -m 1 -oe "RXR[0-9]\{7\}" "$0"` && mv "$0" "${0%/*}/${PREFIX}_${0##*/}"' {} \;
```

**Note:** If a file contains multiple matches of the pattern the first one will be used.

Comment: I'm a bit apprehensive to do the mv right away...
I've done PATTERN='RXR[0-9]\{7\}'
but would like to first see what happens:

grep $PATTERN *.txt

is OK, but: 

grep $PATTERN *.txt -exec sh -c 'grep $PATTERN "$0$"' {} \;

just produces lines like '<filename>:0'

Comment: ... typo above: I DID do "$0" and not "$0$"

Comment: I thought that `PATTERN` was known before as plain text and not as regex. I've edited the answer, now it should do what you want (see the note). Anyway you can test the effects of that command by substituting `mv ...` with `echo mv ..` and removing `> /dev/null`. If something is unclear just ask!

Comment: find -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'PREFIX=`grep -m 1 -oe "RXR[0-9]\{7\}" "$0"` && echo ${PREFIX}' {} \;  - this makes me see all the RXR* results (I'm impressed!); I'll try the rest in a minute

Comment: unfortunately, the second part doesn't seem to work?! (the files seem unchanged). What does ${0%/*} mean (?directory), and ${0##*/} (?filename)? - Actually, the subdirectories are not essential, if I could get it working in a single directory that would already be great...

Comment: No, actually it did work (for a number of files, but due to them starting with RXR... they were all in the middle of the list....).
[I did the command twice now, those files have now ended up with RXR1234567_RXR1234567_letter125.txt, but I hope I can get that sorted with rename...)
I'd still be interested in the meaning of "{0%/*}" and "${0##*/}", if you've got some time to explain that...
And of course the fact that you've done the job with the command line, is simply amazing - Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ajo: `{0%/*}` does the same thing as `dirname` (outputs the directory without the filename) and `${0##*/}` does the same thing as `basename` (outputs the filename without the directory).

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: Thank you Dennis that way is more readable.

Comment: @ajo: Dennis already show you the meaning of them. If you want more info take a look at `man bash`, section `Parameter Expansion`.

Comment: how would I write the argument for 'dirname' in the above??

Comment: Does this look okay?
find -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'PREFIX=$(grep -m 1 -oe "[Rr][Xx][Rr][0-9]\{7\}" "$0") && mv "$0" "$(dirname {})/$(basename {})"' \;

Comment: Not exactly: find -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'PREFIX=$(grep -m 1 -oe "[Rr][Xx][Rr][0-9]\{7\}" "$0") && mv "$0" "$(dirname $0)/${PREFIX}_$(basename $0)"' {} \; You missed the `PREFIX` and the last `{}` that passes the file argument to `sh`. Also I would use `$0` rather `{}` inside the `sh` command.